# How to deal with all data as non-outliers for boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I am new to R project and have to use `boxplot` function to plot the data.

When I use it, boxplot automatically deals with some points as outliers.

But for my case, every points are not outliers. I just wanted to show min/max, 25/75 percentile and median. So I've searched for boxplot function and haven't found an option that deals every points as non-outliers.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: I am not sure this is what you want, but you could try `range=0`.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli What you said is exactly what I want, thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I will put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `range=0`. For example:

```
x <- rlnorm(1000)
boxplot(x, range = 0)
```

[image]